# How to use curl in php,post json data and download file stream

Tags: php, curl

follow codes is php code ,but it don't download anything.

```
 $postdata=$jsonstr;
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);        
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json', 
        //'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postdata)
  ));        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata );
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo "<br/>-------------------<br/>";
    //print_r($output);
    echo "<br/>-------------------<br/>";
    mySaveFile($output, "./file.tmp");        
    curl_close($ch);
```

I get 'file.tmp' always is  size 0.I suspect I set up a mistake for CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
thanks for everyone help.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `$output` and `$info`? You should also show the code for `mySaveFile()`

Comment: $output not print only thiing.$info as follow:

Comment: $output is print no thing,$info as follow:           
Array ( [url] => http://123.232.123.17:9090/services/stdquery/querydown [content_type] => [http_code] => 415 [header_size] => 73 [request_size] => 265 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.109 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0.063 [pretransfer_time] => 0.063 [size_upload] => 109 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 1000 [download_content_length] => 0 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.109 [redirect_time] => 0 )

Comment: `[http_code] => 415` This is the status code for [Unsupported Media Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415).  We don't know anything about the API/service you're using, so I can't say exactly why you're getting that status, but you should read the info on that page and consult the API you're trying to use.